# Is there a way to use ancient cities data with OSMnx?

Tags: openstreetmap, open-source-gis

Is there a way to use [OSMnx](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx) to construct graphs and images of ancient street maps, perhaps using a data source similar to OSM (in the spirit of [OHM](http://www.openhistoricalmap.org/))?

For example, is there a way to construct such a map of say, Tudor London, or ancient Athens?

Answer (score 1):

OSMnx loads data from OpenStreetMap's overpass API and from .osm files. If the data you want to work with isn't available from the overpass API, you can try to export or convert it to a .osm file, then load it into OSMnx.